# How to inherit a gem's class but use configurations from github? (Rubocop gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While implementing Super-Linter, I noticed that it's inheriting from the `rubocop-github` gem, as shown here: https://github.com/github/super-linter/blob/main/TEMPLATES/.ruby-lint.yml

```
---
#######################
# Rubocop Config file #
#######################

inherit_gem:
  rubocop-github:
    - config/default.yml
```

However, the `rubocop-github` gem seems to be a bit dated, with recent updates from June 24th and a `default.yml` config file from over 2 years ago.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is inherit the rubocop gem and then overwrite some of the defaults. Here's what I have right now:

```
---

inherit_gem:
  rubocop-github:
    - config/default.yml

inherit_from:
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubocop/rubocop/master/config/default.yml
  - .rubocop-custom.yml
```

The problem with this is that `rubocop-github` gem (outdated) conflicts with my `rubocop` gem (more up-to-date), so it doesn't work. It would be great if I could do something like this:

```
# Common configuration.
---

inherit_gem:
  rubocop:
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubocop/rubocop/master/config/default.yml
 
inherit_from:
  - .rubocop-custom.yml
```

but this doesn't work. I get the following error in VS Code:

```
can't inherit configuration from the rubocop gem
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:63:in `block in resolve_inheritance_from_gems'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:61:in `each_pair'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:61:in `resolve_inheritance_from_gems'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:50:in `load_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:29:in `options_config='
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:90:in `act_on_options'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:38:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/exe/rubocop:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/exe/rubocop:12:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rubocop:25:in `load'
/usr/bin/rubocop:25:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution to this problem, although there is now a new problem. The gem `rubocop` actually comes with `config/default.yml` already in the gems directory; however, there's a piece of code that actually doesn't allow you to pre-load the configuration file.

This worked for me, at least until the issue with the gem file coming up:

```
# Common configuration.
---

inherit_gem:
  rubocop:
    - config/default.yml

inherit_from:
  - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubocop/rubocop/master/config/default.yml
  - .rubocop-custom.yml
```

Error that gets produced from this:

```
can't inherit configuration from the rubocop gem
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:63:in `block in resolve_inheritance_from_gems'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:61:in `each_pair'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:61:in `resolve_inheritance_from_gems'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:50:in `load_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:29:in `options_config='
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:90:in `act_on_options'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:38:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/exe/rubocop:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/exe/rubocop:12:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rubocop:25:in `load'
/usr/bin/rubocop:25:in `<main>'
```